# Magento 1.9 site where "SQL ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]" keeps showing up after daily reindex (and in other instances)

Tags: sql, magento, caching, error-handling, reindex

I own a Magento CE 1.7 based website where we keep getting variations of the following error, usually after the daily morning site reindex:

"SQL ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.data' in 'field list'
SQL QUERY: SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.`data`, `main_table`.`lifetime`, `main_table`.`expire`, `main_table`.`priority`, `additional_table`.*, IFNULL(al.value, main_table.frontend_label) AS `store_label` FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_label` AS `al` ON al.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id AND al.store_id = 1 WHERE (main_table.entity_type_id (...)"

I have a website down detector set up so that I can know immediately when the site is unavailable. However it obviously doesn't detect whenever the site is unusable due to errors such as “SQL ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]”. That means that my team must be constantly manually (!!!) monitoring if the site is indeed working properly (by clicking on product and category links)!

Usually we surpass the error by just cleaning the cache or performing a new reindex.

My **questions** are the following:

**1 - Is there a way of automatically perform a detection of this type of errors in Magento so that - if it happens - a cache cleaning (or a site reindex) is immediately run and an alert is sent to the webmaster?**

**2 – If such an error is detected, is there a way of it not be shown to the person accessing the site? That is, if the error is detected, is it possible to immediately display a message (“We’ll be back soon”) while the cache is being cleaned or the site reindexed?**

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Thank you!